# Nice edit Wysiwyg width issue

Tags: 7, theming, wysiwyg

I am having problems with the nice edit wysiwyg: The width seems to be set at 100px, and I am not sure how to go about changing this.

[image]

This is the HTML snippet:

[image]

Comment: I don't use Nice Edit WYSIWYG so I don't know the specifics, but the fact that the 100px is being set inline tells me this is either being done in the tpl (not likely) or via JavaScript when this is inserted into the page (very likely), thus it is probably a setting somewhere in the configuration of this module. If you can't find it, perform a search within the module's folder for the string "unselectable" to potentially find where this inner div is being inserted, that should give you a clue.

Comment: thanks. you right its probably the javascript as there is no tpl. i have tried creditor and tinymce and they both work fine. am now thinking of sticking to tinymce because i don't want to mess with the script. thanks again.